# Where does the elder rule appear in the structure theorem for persistent homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis

I'm reading [Computational Topology](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/edelcomp.pdf) (by Edelsbrunner & Harer). The authors describe (pg 180) generating the persistence diagram from a filtration of simplicial complexes. The approach is to define the birth and death times of each homology generator using the elder rule to say that a class dies at step $i$ if it merges with an older class.

My question is: how does this relate to the algebraic perspective where the persistence diagram is given by the decomposition of the persistence module as a finitely generated $\mathbb{N}$-graded module over a PID? Why is it true that the persistence diagram generated using the elder rule is the same as the diagram given by the structure theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a simple example will help.  Let $k$ be a field and consider the following filtered complex of $k$-vector spaces, starting at zero:
$$k \xrightarrow{(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix})} k^2 \xrightarrow{\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)} k.$$

If all you knew was that

- a class is born at time $0$ and at time $1$
- a class dies by time $2$,

then there isn't enough information to uniquely specify the module: it could be $k[t]/(t^3) \oplus t \cdot k[t]/(t)$ or $k[t]/(t^2) \oplus t \cdot k[t]/(t^2)$ in the language of persistence modules as $k[t]$-modules.

The extra information - which is contained in the decomposition of $k[t]$-modules but not in just the birth/death times - needed to reconstruct the module is the elder rule: which class was born earlier?  This tells us among the classes that are merged at time $2$, there is an older class which survives from time $0$ to time $2$, so that the interval decomposition contains the module $k[t]/(t^3)$.  So the correct decomposition is $k[t]/(t^3) \oplus t \cdot k[t]/(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I understood correctly, the elder rule is implicit within the structure theorem and is encoded by the maps in the persistence module? If, for example, the second map was a projection onto the second component, then the birth/death information would be the same but the decomposition would be other one you gave.

Comment: Precisely.  The interval decomposition gives all the information about the persistence module, since it *is* the module, so you don't need additional rules.  But birth and death times alone do not give the full picture, which is why you need something like the elder rule to disambiguate.   FWIW, you can mostly avoid thinking about the elder rule if you keep track of all the information in a persistence module together.